# Getting values from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

**user_table:**

- user_id
- user_name

**leave_type:**

- leave_id
- leave_name

**leave_taken**

- id
- leave_id
- applied_by (user_id)
- approved_by (user_id)

My end result should be

**Result:**

- leave_name
- applied_by (user_name)
- approved_by (user_name)

This is what I have tried and got stuck at. I'm sorry for not providing what I tried the first time I posted this question.

**Option 1:**

```
SELECT leave_type.leave_name, users.user_name as applied_by, 
leaves.no_of_days, leaves.leave_date, leaves.leave_upto_date, 
leaves.leave_status 
from leaves
join leave_type on leaves.leave_type = leave_type.id
join users on leaves.applied_by = users.id
```

**Option 2:**

```
 SELECT leave_type.leave_name, users.user_name as applied_by, 
    leaves.approved_by, leaves.no_of_days, leaves.leave_date, 
    leaves.leave_upto_date, leaves.leave_status, leaves.approved_on
    FROM leave_type, leaves, users  
    WHERE leave_type.id = leaves.leave_type 
    AND leaves.applied_by = users.id
```

P.S. I'm new to MySQL & I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: *"This is what I have come up with but"*  - But what?

Comment: So, what happened when you ran those options. Any error, undesired result? And how then? Help us help you.

Comment: @GolezTrol I got the desired result however just one column leaves.approved_by remains id and I'm not able to fetch the names from the users table

Comment: So you need to get the user names for both the user who applied and the user who approved. Add that to the question. That is relevant information. Without it, your question is too unclear to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved your desired result with the following query. I'm not very sure if this is the best way though.

```
SELECT leave_type.leave_name, users.user_name AS applied_by, 
    (SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE id = leaves.approved_by) AS approved_by, 
    leaves.no_of_days, leaves.leave_date, leaves.leave_upto_date, 
    leaves.leave_status 
    FROM leaves
    JOIN leave_type on leaves.leave_type = leave_type.id
    JOIN users on leaves.applied_by = users.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to join the same table twice, you can provide it with an alias.

In this case, the user table has been joined with two different aliases. I've made the aliases in capitals, so it's easier to find them, but of course, you can write them however you want.

```
SELECT 
  leave_type.leave_name, 
  APPLY_USER.user_name as applied_by, 
  APPROVE_USER.user_name as approved_by, 
  leaves.no_of_days, leaves.leave_date, leaves.leave_upto_date, 
  leaves.leave_status 
from leaves
join leave_type on leaves.leave_type = leave_type.id
join users AS APPLY_USER on leaves.applied_by = APPLY_USER.id 
join users AS APPROVE_USER on leaves.applied_by = APPROVE_USER.id
```